# Having trouble creating shopping cart [PHP and XML]

Tags: php, xml, session, shopping-cart

I’m working on a website that contains four web pages and an xml file.
The menu.xml file contains menu for edibles and looks something like this

```
<menu>
    <item name="Pizzas">
        <category name="Onions" small="6.85" large="10.85">
        </category>
        <category name="Peppers" small="6.85" large="10.85">
        </category>
    </item>
    <item name="Salads">
        <category name="Garden" small="3.50" large="4.50">
        </category>
    </item>
</menu>
```

The menu.xml file is eXtensible and we can add new *items* or new *categories*.
The main page of website `index.php` displays in a drop down all the items available in the (fake pizza) shop.

The code for parsing xml and displaying items in the dropdown menu is:

```
<form action="display.php" method="post">
    <select name="foodType">
        <?php
            $dom = simplexml_load_file("menu.xml");
            foreach($dom->xpath("/menu/item") as $item)
            {
        ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $item['name'] ?>" > 
                    <?php echo $item['name']; ?>
                </option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Let's Eat" />
</form>
```

Upon reaching display.php I have stored in `$_SESSION[‘foodType’]` the value of `$_POST[‘foodType’]`
This page displays all the categories of an item using the following code.

```
    <?php
        $selected = $_SESSION['foodType'];
            $dom = simplexml_load_file("menu.xml");
            $i = 0;
            foreach($dom -> xpath('item[@name="' . $selected . '"]/category') as $category)
            {
                    echo '<li>';
                    echo '<h3>' . $category['name'] . '</h3>';
                    echo '</li>';
                    $_SESSION[$selected][$i] = "{$category['name']}";               
    ?>
                <form action="calculator.php" method="post">
                <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Small</th>
                        <th>Large</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center;height:20px;"><input type="text" name="small[<?php echo $i ?>]" /></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;height:20px"><input type="text" name="large[<?php echo $i ?>]" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
     <?php
                $i =($i+1);
            }?>
```

So far so good. The problem I’m encountering is in calculator.php.
This page is supposed to:

- Display the currently purchased items.
- Display the price of those items against their names.
- Proceed to `checkout.php` or `index.php`depending upon user's submission

  I can't figure how to store the data in `$_SESSION` superglobal so that upon calculation, I'm able to uniquely identify the foodType of Pizza, or sald, or any type that is added subsuquently. In fact I'm completely at a loss and don't how how to work this page out.

I'm really sorry if the question seems too long. But it has taken me all day and I still couldn't figure out how to go about it. Therefore asked the question in detail so that its easy for you guys to help me out.
Thanks so much in advance. Anyone's help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding $_SESSION, you are trying to retrieve a value which does not exist yet.
Do the following in display.php

Gets the user submitted data into display.php
`$selected = $_POST["foodType"];`
 Store the user submitted data into a session variable,
`$_SESSION["foodType"] = $selected;`

Now session data can be retrieved later by `$_SESSION["foodType"]`

Also, add `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the beginning of display.php, in case if you see `$_SESSION undefined` message

Comment: Thanks buddy. But the code snippet I showed assumes that I have stored appropriate values in `$_SESSION` and `$_SESSION` contains the value selected in the first page. Also I have already used `session_start` at the beginning.

Comment: Can you post the code which  stores appropriate values in $_SESSION ?

Comment: Here is the line of code that stores the appropriate value in session<br> `session_start();
 $_SESSION['foodType'] = $_POST['foodType'];`

Comment: Code looks good.... I guess then you are not able to retrieve this `$_SESSION['foodType']` in calculator.php ....do you mind posting that as well.

Comment: No I am able to retrieve the `$_SESSION['foodType']` there as well. The problem I can't solve is that once the user has selected pizza, `$_SESSION['foodType']` will contain Pizza, now the user goes back to index.php and selects another food type say salads and hits enter, the previous value of Pizza stored in `S_SESSION['foodType']` would be lost and updated with Salads, whereas to maintain my shopping cart, I need to have some storage mechanism for retrieving all the values later. This means that I am supposed to store all the "item" values at all times. How to do that?

Comment: This should help.
Instead of storing a value in `$_SESSION["foodType"] `  ..the below code stores an array. 

 if ( isset($_SESSION["foodType"]) ) {
    $foodtype_count = count($_SESSION["foodType"]) + 1;
    $_SESSION["foodType"][$foodtype_count] = $_POST["foodType"];

    print_r($_SESSION["foodType"]);

    foreach ($_SESSION["foodType"] as $foodtype) {
        echo "loop $foodtype <br>";
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION["foodType"][0] = $_POST["foodType"];
}

Comment: Sorry for responding late buddy. But I think this is gonna help coz all i needed was a way of uniquely indexing for item type and apparently the code you have suggested does just that. Will get back to you after implementing. Thanks buddy!